# NameError: Name view_post is not defined

Tags: django, django-views

## update

I apologise for yet another simple Django question but I cannot find what I'm after.

Project: Blog
I'm trying to URL design to the app using Django 2.0

[mysite/url.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XY73.png)

[Error after run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yUZU.png)

[server error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQRnR.png)

Comment: you have not imported view_post in urls.py

Comment: how can I import in urls.py?

Comment: see i have post as answer

Comment: Please don't link to screenshots. Copy and past the code and traceback in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Django 2.0 adds the new `path` function for urls : https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.0/ref/urls/#path

`path` doesn't use regex anymore.

You have two solutions

1) Use `path` and change the url pattern to new django format

```
from django.urls import path 
urlpatterns = [
    url('/post/<int:pk>/', ...)
]
```

2) Keep you regex and use `re_path`

```
from django.urls import re_path
urlpatterns = [
    re_path('^/post/(?<pk>[0-9]+)/$', ...)
]
```

Note that using `url` function is still possible but will be likely be deprecated in a next version. It has been renamed into `re_path` in Django 2.0

Answer (score 1):

update you urls.py file.

you need to import `view_post` in urls.py file

```
from blog.views import view_post
#from appname.file.py import (class/func)name
```

As you are using `view_post` in urls.py so you also need to import it in that file.

Comment: Page not found (404)
Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/1

Using the URLconf defined in mysitee.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    admin/
    blog/
    ^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$ [name='view_post']

The current path, post/1, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

Comment: update your question with code instead of pictures and post your error as text code.

Comment: update your url `post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$` with `post/(?P<pk>\d+)/$`.

Comment: i want http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/1 by first blog post

Comment: update your `url.py` `post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$` with `post/(?P<pk>\d+)/$` and when you will hit `127.0.0.1:8000/post/1` and then it will return your desired result.